# Invalid pthread_t value?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am currently writing a piece of code where I want to perform an action against every thread on a system except (possibly) a single specified thread.  I'd like to do something like:

```
void do_something_to_all_but(pthread_t except = PTHREAD_NULL) {
    for (pthread_t tid : myThreads)
    {
        if (pthread_equal(tid, except)) continue;
        do_something(tid);
    }
}
```

However, I have not (as of yet) found an appropriate value to use for `PTHREAD_NULL`.  I know that (at least in Linux) `pthread_t` is defined as an opaque unsigned long int (presumably to disguise an internal representation), but I'd hope there's a (preferably portable) way to specify a `pthread_t` value that is guaranteed not to compare to any valid `pthread_t` value.

Comment: Your code suggests C++, but you're using the pthread C libraries directly.  If you have a modern C++ compiler, you might consider using `std::thread` instead, and if not you could take a look at `boost::thread`.  Those make better enable you to do what you're after.

Comment: Yes, I am using C++11 and std::thread.  However, I need to pull a native_handle() (read: pthread_t) in order to invoke pthread_kill() in order to signal each thread, which is part of what do_something() does.

Comment: Your function with default value behaves differently than with a given value, so you should use two different functions, e.g. `do_something_to_all_but(pthread_t)` and `do_something_to_all()`, this would get you rid of your issue too